# Session management in the client side of gwt application

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc, gwt-ext

Hello All
I am working on the gwt-ext application.On the server side I am using Hibernate.
I am mantaining session on the server side.it's time out is 5 minute (In action class).

Now take a secenario in which a user logged in & remains it open for five minute.After five minutes expires it do a click on a button on the screen.There is some process on the client side & it is of 2 minutes and after that it goes for a server call.When it go for server call it is already session out (as session time is 5 minutes which is already expired).And a message of session out popped up with redirecting the login page.

In this whole case user feels that I am active on the system (After 5 minutes on the client side actually) so why I am redirected to login page.

Reason behind is that that session is maintained on the server side.And server hit is after seven minutes.

So I am thinking to maitain the session on the client side also.How to achieve this in the gwt based application.
Is there any other way to do solve this issue.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to check the server regularly, if a timeout has occurred. You would have to write a servlet method which performs that check without renewing the server session timeout! And of course this will result in lots of server hits. (Not necessarily a bad method though!)

---

But maybe I would use a dfifferent solution, which tries to keep a timer on the client side approximately synchronous with the server's timer, e.g.

Client side:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Timer;

public class ClientTimers {

    private static final Timer SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED_TIMER = new Timer() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Warn the user, that the session may have expired.
            // You could then show a login dialog, etc...
        }
    };

    public static void renewSessionTimer() {

        // First cancel the previous timer
        SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED_TIMER.cancel();

        // Schedule again in 5 minutes (maybe make that configurable?)
        // Actually, let's subtract 10 seconds from that, because our timer
        // won't be synchronized perfectly with the server's timer.
        SESSION_MAY_HAVE_EXPIRED_TIMER.schedule(5 * 60 * 1000 - 10000);
    }
}
```

I assume that your server session timeout gets renewed every time the client performs an interaction with the server, e.g. a GWT-RPC call (if the session hasn't timed out already).

So on the client side, I would then also renew the client timer, in order to keep it roughly synchronous:

```
 myService.performSomeAction(...) {

     @Override
     public void onSuccess(String result) {

          ClientTimers.renewSessionTimer();

          // remaining onSuccess handling
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

          if (failedBecauseOfSessionTimeout()) {

              // redirect to login

          } else {

              ClientTimers.renewSessionTimer();

              // remaining onFailure handling...
          }
     }
 }
```

Don't forget to call renewSessionTimer() on all interactions (especially directly after login).

**Important Note:** For all security checks, only use the server session. The client "session timer" is just a convenience for the user. Don't make security/authorization checks dependent on that timer, or on any kind of client session.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your scenario when a user does a click on a button on the screen. You can make a server hit and check whether session is alive or not.

let me know if I have get the situation or not.

Answer (score 1):

This code will do log out automatically as the time out occurs.For my code I want that on click or key down it should do logout.
Case is like:If user is logged in and time to log out is 5 min.User don't do any activity on the screen than right now as per the above code it will log out automatically as the 5 min complete.

Now my requirement is that if user logged in and it doesn't do any thing for 5 mins.It should not do any logged out automatically.Instead of logging out on completion of 5 min,If user do click or key down on 6 min then it should do the log out process.

Basically the log out process as the timer exceed the specified time should be done on the user activity, not automatically.

Answer (score 0):

do get the every page event I have don this....it is working fine.

```
Ext.get("pagePanel").addListener("click", new EventCallback() {
            @Override
            public void execute(EventObject e) {
                //MessageBox.alert("On Mouse Click");
        });

        Ext.get("pagePanel").addListener("keydown", new EventCallback() {

            @Override
            public void execute(EventObject e) { //
                //MessageBox.alert("On Key Press Click");
            }
        });
```